# Proving an equation in set theory: $L \setminus (M ∪ N) = (L \setminus M) ∩ (L \setminus N)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This may be simple, but it just won't work for me.
 Here's what I need to proof:

> L \ (M ∪ N) = (L \ M) ∩ (L \ N)

And this is what I did:

> L \ (M ∪ N)
>  = L \ ({x: x ∈ M ∨ x ∈ N})
>  = {x: x ∈ L ∧ (x ∉ M ∨ x ∉ N)}
> = {x: (x ∈ L ∧ x ∉ M) ∨ (x ∈ L ∧ x ∉ N )}
> = (L / M) ∪ (L / N)

I'm pretty sure it should say `(L \ M) ∩ (L \ N)` but somehow I always end up with
 `(L / M) ∪ (L / N)` instead.

Comment: There are several other posts about the same identity:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12322/how-to-prove-demorgans-law
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367614/proving-an-equation-in-set-theory
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810091/prove-or-disprove-x-backslash-a-cup-b-x-backslash-a-cap-x-backslash-b
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786677/prove-a-setminusb-cup-c-a-setminus-b-cap-a-setminus-c-using-elemen
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172685/set-differences-and-union
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1775333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is with the conclusion

> = {x: x ∈ L ∧ (x ∉ M ∨ x ∉ N)}

Following the sequence:

> L \ (M ∪ N)
>   = L \ ({x: x ∈ M ∨ x ∈ N})

What you need to do is write:

$$x \in L\setminus (M\cup N) $$ $$\iff x \in L \land x \notin (M\cup N)$$ $$ \iff x \in L \land x \notin M \land x \notin N$$

This last expression follows from DeMorgan's: the negation $(x \in M \lor x \in N)$ is given by $$\lnot(x \in M \lor x \in N) $$ $$\iff \lnot (x \in M) \land \lnot (x \in M)
$$ $$\iff  x\notin M \land x\notin N$$

Then we can write $$x \in L \land x \notin M \land x \notin N $$ $$\iff x \in L \land x \notin M \land x \in L \land x \notin N$$ 
$$\iff x \in (L\setminus M) \land x \in (L\setminus N)$$ $$ \iff x \in (L\setminus M) \cap (L\setminus N)$$

Comment: You kinda saved my day. Next time I'm working on something like this I won't be as lost as I was here. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: @amWhy: Very nice answer! +1