# Prove or disprove $X \backslash A \cup B = (X\backslash A) \cap (X \backslash B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have to prove or disprove the statement

$X \backslash A \cup B = (X\backslash A) \cap (X \backslash B)$

I can draw the picture and what I'm getting is that this statement is true, but I don't know how to start the proof.

Comment: Start with "unwinding" the definition of $X \backslash (A \cup B)$. We have that $x \in X \backslash (A \cup B)$ iff $x \in X$ **and** $x \notin (A \cup B)$ iff $x \in X$ **and** ($x \notin A$ **and** $x \notin B$) ...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with "unpacking" what it means to be an element of the set on the right; then further unpack using our trusty definitions of union, setminus, intersections etc.

$$\begin{align} x \in X\backslash(A\cup B) & \iff x\in X \land x\notin (A\cup B)\\ \\ 
& \iff x \in X \land (x \notin A \land x \notin B) \\ \\ 
&\iff (x \in X \land x\notin A) \land (x \in X \land x \notin B) \\ \\ &\iff 
(x \in X \setminus A) \land (x \in X\setminus B)\\ \\
& \iff x \in (X\setminus A)\cap (X\setminus B)\end{align}$$

Since we have bidirectional implications ($\iff)$ when moving from one line to another, it works "backwards", too.

Hence $$X\setminus (A\cup B) = (X\setminus A) \cap (X \setminus B)$$

Comment: +1 Personally, I would write this proof in the other direction, making it a simplification problem, so that the step 'duplicate conjunct $\;x \in X\;$' changes into the more natural 'remove duplicate conjunct $\;x \in X\;$'.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you think the equation is true, one way to prove it is to consider first $x\in X~\backslash~(A\cup B)$ and show it is in $(X~\backslash ~A)\cap(X~\backslash~ B)$, and then consider $x\in(X~\backslash ~A)\cap(X~\backslash~ B)$ and show it is in $X~\backslash~(A\cup B)$.

Answer (score 0):

$x \in X -(A\cup B) \Leftrightarrow x \in X \wedge x \not \in A \wedge x \not \in B$
$x \in (X -A)\cap (X-B) \Leftrightarrow (x \in X \wedge x \not \in A) \wedge (x \in X \wedge x \not \in B)$
It is now clear these are the same.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x\in X \setminus (A \cup B) \Leftrightarrow x \in X$ and $x \notin A \cup B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x \in X$ and $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x \in X \setminus A$ and $x \in X \setminus B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x \in (X \setminus A) \cap (X \setminus B)$