# Set Differences and Union: $A \setminus (B \cup C) = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \setminus C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

True or false. Prove why.
$A \setminus (B \cup C) = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \setminus C)$

If $x$ is in the right side, then $x$ is in $A$ and not in $B$, or $x$ is in $A$ and not in $C$. $x$ is in $A$, and either not $B$ or not $C$. Is this right?

Comment: Why don't you draw a Venn diagram and see what happens?

Comment: oh. so x should be in just a and not the intersection of a and b and a and c.

Comment: And its a good idea to check this.. $A\(B\cup C)=(A\B)\cap (A\C)$?

Comment: that makes sense. thanks.

Comment: the true relation is: $$A \setminus (B \cup C) = (A \setminus B)\setminus C $$

Answer (score 1):

what happens if $x$ is in $A$ and $B$ but not in $C$?

Comment: then it's still true. because x is in A, but not in either B or C. Then x is in A and B but not C.

Comment: nope. since it's in $A$ and $B$ it's in $A$ and $B \cup C$ and therefore it's not in the left side. But since it's in $A$ and not in $C$ then it's in $A \setminus C$ and therefore in the right side.

Comment: that makes sense now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Counter example $A=\mathbb{R}, B=\mathbb{Q}$ and $C=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$.