# Proving that $M \setminus {( A \cup B)} = (M \setminus A)\cap(M \setminus B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I want to prove that the above terms are logically equivalent.

M is a set and $A,B\subseteq M$.

$x \in M\setminus ( A\cup B ) $

$\Leftrightarrow x \in M \wedge x\notin A \cup B $

$\Leftrightarrow x \in M \wedge x\notin A \wedge x\notin B$

$\Leftrightarrow (x \in M \wedge x\notin A) \wedge (x \in M \wedge  x\notin B)$

$\Leftrightarrow x \in (M\setminus A) \cap (M\setminus B) $

Is this a correct proof? Can this be improved?

Comment: Yes, it can be improved. For example, don't use $\{,\} $ when not needed. Using them makes several of these steps incorrect. Also the line mentioning $\lor $ is meaningless.

Comment: The title makes no sense. Sets are not logically equivalent.

Comment: You simply removed a line, instead of fixing it. Now I do not think it is clear why the first equivalence you wrote holds.

Comment: You probably mean to say that the sets are equal - sets are not logical propositions, so they cannot be equivalent. However, your proof (when viewed as a proof that the sets are equal) is indeed correct.

Comment: I removed the curly parentheses. But I have to keep the parentheses for $A \cup B$, or do I?

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Youre right! Fixed the line with the $\vee$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You are trying to prove $M\setminus(A\cup B)=(M\setminus A)\cap(M\setminus B)$.  Prove the following very basic lemmas and then apply them to this problem:

*Lemma 1*: For sets $X,Y$ contained in a universe $U$ we have $(X\cup Y)^C=X^C\cap Y^C$.

*Lemma 2*: For sets $X,Y$ contained in a universe $U$ we have $X\setminus Y=X\cap Y^C$.

*Lemma 3*: For sets $X,Y,Z$ contained in a universe $U$ we have $X\cap Y\cap Z=X\cap Y\cap X\cap Z$.

**NB**: You probably take Lemma 2 as a definition; most folks do.

**EDIT:** Your current proof (edited after I first posted) is correct and clear.