# Proof verification: prove $A\setminus (B\cup C) = (A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Can someone please verify whether my proof is logically correct? :)

Proof: Let $x\in A\setminus (B\cup C)$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin B\cup C$. If $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, then $x\in A\setminus B$. If $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$, then $x\in A\setminus C$. In either case, $x\in (A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$. Then $A\setminus (B\cup C) \subset (A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$.

Let $x\in (A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$. Then $x\in A\setminus B$ and $x\in A\setminus C$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$ or $x\notin C$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in (B\cup C)^{c}$. Then $x\in A\cap (B\cup C)^{c}$. Then $x\in A\setminus (B\cup C)$. Then $(A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C) \subset A\setminus (B\cup C)$. Therefore, $A\setminus (B\cup C) = (A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$. $\square$

Comment: Did you compare it to the proof in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775333/proving-that-m-setminus-a-cup-b-m-setminus-a-capm-setminus-b?rq=1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first paragraph, you (seemingly) make a jump from $x \notin B \cup C$ to $x \notin B$ or $x \notin C$. I'd like to see that justified.

More problematic is your claim "In either case, $x \in (A \setminus B) \cap (A \setminus C)$" proceeding from "$x \in A \setminus B$ or $x \in A \setminus C$." That $x \in A \setminus B$ does not imply $x \in (A \setminus B) \cap (A \setminus C)$. You would need to show that $x \in A \setminus B$ **and** $x \in A \setminus C$ in order to conclude $x \in (A \setminus B) \cap (A \setminus C)$.

Comment: I agree, I am not sure how to turn that "or" into an "and".

Comment: @numericalorange Try this: you have $x \notin B \cup C$ (1). Now assume $x \in B$; then $x \in B \cup C$, which contradicts (1), so $x \notin B$. Now assume $x \in C$; then $x \in B \cup C$, which contradicts (1), so $x \notin C$. You now have $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

> If $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, then $x\in A\setminus B$. If $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$, then $x\in A\setminus C$. In either case, $x\in (A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$.

In that part, you just proved that either $x \in A\setminus B$, either $x \in A\setminus C$, so $x\in (A\setminus B)\cup (A\setminus C)$, but not in $ (A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$.