# Prove $A\setminus(B \cup C) = (A \setminus B) \cap (A \setminus C)$ using element chasing?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How can I prove  $A \setminus(B \cup C) = (A \setminus B) \cap (A \setminus C)$ using element chasing? I need to verify that it is correct and show the steps of element chasing.

Comment: Hi Zack, I edited your question for math style. That would be a sample of how to use LaTeX syntax. It would be good if you write down what you tried. As a hint, try proving both inclusions.

Comment: I honestly am not sure where to start as this is the first time I have seen this method.

Comment: Take $x$ from the left hand side and show it's an element of the right hand side. Then do the same with roles of left and right hand side interchanged.

Comment: First try to show that every element in the left hand side (one in $A$ but not in the union $B\cup C$) must lie in the right hand side. Then work the other way round.

Comment: What is element chasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part I: To prove $\subseteq$:
Let $x\in A\setminus(B\cup C)$.  Then $x\in A$, and $x\notin (B\cup C)$.  In particular, that means $x\notin B$.  Hence $x\in A\setminus B$.  Since $x\notin (B\cup C)$, in particular $x\notin C$.  Hence $x\in A \setminus C$.  Combining, we get $x\in (A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$.  Since $x$ was arbitrary, this proves $A\setminus (B\cup C)\subseteq (A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$.

Part II: To prove $\supseteq$:
I leave as an exercise.

Comment: Awesome, figured it out, just worked backwards from what you explained here.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to know
$$X = Y \Leftrightarrow (X \subset Y) \wedge (Y \subset X)$$
and
$$(X \subset Y) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \in X \Rightarrow x \in Y$$